# What is the ga:visits equivalent in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-data-api

I'm seeing [the list of metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/migration-api-schema-mapping) available in GA4, and am looking for the "ga:visits" equivalent for GA4 but that seems to be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several years ago Google Analytics renamed visits to sessions ([Article 1](https://www.webfx.com/blog/marketing/google-analytics-sessions-users/), [Article 2](https://www.hotjar.com/google-analytics/glossary/sessions/)). `sessions` in GA4 is the closest equivalent to `ga:visits`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an equivalent for universal analytics ga:visits, in GA4 at this time.

At the time of writing the Analytics Data api is still in early preview version of the api, I think your going to have to wait a while before it settles down.